# Firebase authorisation and registration

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a basic app for my small educational business.

We supply English teachers to schools and I want a way for parents to access the progress reports and other data about their children.

I'm using Android Studio and Flutter as well as Firebase to store the data. I don't want parents to be able to access the data of every child, obviously, but they may have more than one child at the school.

So I need to limit their read privileges to just the records that relate to their children. I'd like to do that by giving them some sort of registration code that they could use the first time they access the app so that we can ensure that they are only being given access to the correct records. Subsequent logins would then be via email and password.

Is there a way to do this with Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Your use-case sounds feasible, but it is really broad which makes it impossible to answer it completely-yet-succinctly.

Specific on what to do with the registration code that associates a parent with their children, when you generate the registration code, you write that code and the associated children to a database. Then when the parent registers with that code, you associate their account (UID) with the code. You'll just have to ensure that the code is sufficiently long and random that it can't be reasonably guessed by another user.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that that was the solution but I wasn't confident enough to start trying to write the code if it was going to end up a complete mess.